# If $R = k[x]_{(x)}$, why is $R_{(0)}\cong k(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I'm having some problems understanding why this should be true. I don't have a strong background in ring theory and I'm not even sure if $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. I would like to know how to prove the isomorphism in the title.

Comment: Does $R_{(0)}$ denotes the localization at the prime ideal $(0)$ ?

Comment: @Watson That's right, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $R$ is an integral domain, since it is a subring of the field $k(x)$. Therefore, your question follows from the following result.

**Claim**: if $R$ is an integral domain, then $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and $R_{(0)} \cong \mathrm{Frac}(R)$.

Indeed, $(0) \subset R$ is a prime ideal, because if $xy \in (0)$, then either $x=0$ or $y=0$ (since $R$ is an integral domain). 
Now, $R_{(0)} = (R \setminus \{0\})^{-1}R$, by definition. This is precisely the fraction field of $R$, which is $k(x)$ in your case.

Comment: Concretely, elements of $R$ are quotients $f(X) / g(X)$ where $f, g \in k[X]$ and $g(0) \neq 0$. But your specific question only requires $R$ to be an _integral domain_.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Mark : you're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask further questions ; it might not be easy to deal with localizations, the first time… !

Comment: I will ask if I had any problems. Your answer is very understandable.

Comment: Looking back at your answer, I'm confused by how we know that $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is the same as $\mathrm{Frac}(k[x]) = k(x)$? Will you please explain how this is true?

Comment: @Mark : we have $k[x] \subset R \subset k(x)$, so that taking fraction fields yields $k(x) \subset \mathrm{Frac}(R) \subset k(x)$.

Comment: But then why is $R \subseteq k(x)$?

Comment: @Mark : By definition, $k(x) = k[x]_{(0)}$. Since $(0) \subset (x)$ (i.e. we have an inclusion of multiplicative subsets $k[x] \setminus (x) \subset k[x] \setminus \{0\}$), we get a ring morphism $R \to k(x)$ which is injective.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond so quickly and for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is a prime ideal since $k[x]$ (and hence $R$) is an integral domain. By definition of integral domain, $ab = 0 \implies a=0$ or $b= 0$, that is $a \in (0)$ or $b \in (0)$. Localizing at $0$ is formally inverting all nonzero polynomials, that is, elements of $R_{(0)}$ are of the form
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
For $f, \ g \in R$, both nonzero. Then, note that the composition $k [ x] \to R_{(0)}$ has the property that all nonzero elements are units in the image. Recall that we have a universal property of fraction fields in this case, and this should be enough to conclude the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is very helpful.